# Writing own the_* function for the Wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to provide my own `the_attribute()` function in my wordpress plugin. Let's say my plugin saves the custom meta tag "myAttribute". If I now declare

```
function the_attribute () {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myAttribute', true);
}
```

it will not work as `$post` is only visible inside the templates loop and not in my plugin. So how can I hook into the loop to have an accessible post object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just call the global $post

```
function the_attribute () {
    global $post;
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myAttribute', true);
}
```